# How to get bottom to top level hierarchy tree

Tags: mysql, treeview, hierarchical-data

Below is my table structure

**Id FirstName ReportingTo**

6    A

9   B   6

10  C   6

11  D   9

12  E   9

16  F   11

20  G   12

23  H   20

This is my table structure, I want an output that will give me a result from bottom to top hierarchy.
Means if I put Id = 23 then it should be give - (20,12,9,6).
As I am using MySQL 5.7 so With Recursive function I can't use.

```
select id, firstname, reporting_to from (select * from users order by
id) products_sorted, (select @pv := '23') initialisation where
find_in_set(reporting_to, @pv) and length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',',
id))
```

But it gives only a single row. I need the entire hierarchy from bottom to top.

Comment: This answer to this question regarding recursive queries also addresses how to do this on MySQL 5.x: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737203/4517964

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I have already used the code that you described, but it give top to bottom hierarchy, I need bottom to top. Sorry if anything wrong

Comment: @Andrew why would you need a recursion for that?

Comment: Just run a simple query in a loop. That's the most basic thing